# Getting graph disconnected error when trying to build encoder-decoder model in Keras

Tags: python, keras, encoder-decoder

I am trying to implement, in Keras, a simplified version of the encoder-decoder model based on the one in the image below (source: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.07685.pdf). Note there is only one encoder and decoder in this model, they have been rolled out in the image for clarity.

I'm only focusing on the bottom branch and not including attention and a style label s_i for now. I've been following this [Keras tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html) on seq2seq models for guidance. [Here](https://github.com/Johnxjp/stackoverflow_question/blob/master/benchmark_model.py) is my script where I define this model.

[image]

Training runs successfully but I get the errors below during the inference step.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/run_model.py", line 110, in <module>
decoded_sentence = benchmark_obj.inference(test_encoded, id2word, max_sequence_length)
File "/benchmark_model.py", line 173, in inference
encoder_inference = Model(self.encoder_inputs, self.encoder_states)
File "/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 91, in __init__
self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
File "/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 235, in _init_graph_network
self.inputs, self.outputs)
File "/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1489, in _map_graph_network
str(layers_with_complete_input))
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("decoder_inputs_forward:0", shape=(?, 1, 13105), dtype=float32) at layer "decoder_inputs_forward". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: ['encoder_inputs']
```

During inference I create a new encoder and decoder, as per the tutorial, with the same weights as the ones trained. However, I don't include the backward transfer part as this was just for training the model. I am guessing this is the cause of the problem, because during training the encoder and decoder are almost circularly linked but during inference I only want to focus on the forward transfer.

I'm not sure however how I should go about fixing this issue. I thought maybe I should create two independent encoder / decoders for the forward and backward transfer parts and have them share weights but not sure if this is sensible. I'm a beginner with Keras so explanations without assumptions would be hugely appreciated. Thanks.

### Some further context which might help:

I am attempting to transfer the style of text. I have two non-parallel corpuses for styles A and B and hence this is an unsupervised problem. This is why the decoder during forward transfer uses the output at timestep t-1 as the input at timestep t. However, during backward transfer, the decoder aims to reconstruct the original sentence and so uses the ground truth as input. Thus two decoder input layers are created.

### Update:

I have solved this specific error. It turned out that I was overwriting the output from the encoder (self.encoder_states) during forward transfer with the output from the encoder during backward transfer. The backward transfer encoder takes input from the decoder which was not passed. Instead I was calling Model(self.encoder_inputs, self.encoder_states).

Following on from this, I am wondering if the approach I have taken is the simplest for implementing this model. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: I'm trying to implement this paper, has the dataset released? did you prepare your own dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this specific error. It turned out that I was overwriting the output from the encoder (self.encoder_states) during forward transfer with the output from the encoder during backward transfer. The backward transfer encoder takes input from the decoder which was not passed. Instead I was calling Model(self.encoder_inputs, self.encoder_states).

Answer (score -1):

When you are using [keras functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) to define model, you will need to connect the layers that is,

```
input_tensor = Input((784,))
x = Dense(16, activation="relu")(inputs) # inputs -> x
output_tensor = Dense(10, activation="softmax") # inputs -> x -> outputs

model = Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=output_tensor)
```

in your case, you haven't connected the layers (nodes) in the graph.

Lines 61:62

```
    self.encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(max_timestep, self.input_dims), name="encoder_inputs")
    self.encoder = LSTM(self.latent_dims, return_state=True, dropout=dropout, name="encoder")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Don't I link them in line 63? 
`encoder_output, state_h, state_c = self.encoder(self.encoder_inputs)`